# Occasionally gets null from (View).findViewByID

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, findviewbyid

I hava a Android app @ Android Market. And Im keep getting some crash reports that claims that some users get a NullPointerException.

I've located the code that seems to be causing this problem.

It's  in a ArrayAdapters getView method.

```
if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.subcatategory_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

                if(holder == null){
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                }
            }



            TextView tl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);

            tl.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.styleA);
```

The last line in this snippet seems to be causing the crash. However I've never experienced it, and I've been testing it on several devices.

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:

subcategory_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:weightSum="80">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:text="C.r"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/default_textcolor"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="53"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_bb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/default_textcolor"

        android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_ba"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/default_textcolor"
        android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_a"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/default_textcolor"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_b"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/default_textcolor"
        />
    </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
       android:layout_weight="10"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/arrow"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:paddingLeft="-10dip"
           android:paddingRight="10dip"
           android:src="@drawable/arrow"
           android:visibility="visible" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you psot your layout subcatategory_row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have had this issue on published apps.
After a lot of soul searching I recreated it - in two different ways !

Reason 1 ) Turns out the reason it is null , is that there was no memory at the time to allocate it. Just had to write more protective code and shut down.

Reason 2 ) Dalvik in some cases got convinced that I was not using it and deallocated it. I had to alter my code to make sure it was more "hooked together" in Dalvik's eye.

However 9 times out of 10 , it was reason 1.

The problem is that you can't reproduce it as you are using test devices , other people have all sorts of stuff running at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1) Do you shut down the application if null? 2) How do you hook it together? With a viewHolder as described in answer below?

Comment: You should wrap it yes , keeps dalvik away but that example still fails in lack of RAM.  Do a Toast message and close down.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the `TextView` inside your ViewHolder object

Here's an example of something I've used

```
class DataObjectContainer {
    TextView title;
}

public View getView(final Activity activity, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final DataObjectContainer container;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = (LinearLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dataobjectitem, null);

        container = new DataObjectContainer();

        container.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);

        convertView.setTag(container);

    } else {
        container = ((DataObjectContainer) convertView.getTag());
    }

    container.title.setText(getValueString(DataObject.Table.NAME));

    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: Im greatful for your input. It might event work. But why doesn't my solution work??

Comment: I can't say for sure why your code isn't working.  One thing I noticed right away is that you never do anything with your `ViewHolder` object.  My code above is based on many examples I've found overtime with regard to working with Adapters.

Comment: Thats not true. I use the content of the view holder when a item is tapped. Just didn't include that code :)

Comment: Also, are you returning `v` at the end of the `getView` method?

Comment: absolutely, the code works fore all the devices (>5) I've tested it on. The error occurs rarely.

Comment: What does `ViewHolder` contain? Because based on your code above, it doesn't appear to contain anything specific to the current item in the list.

Comment: Just some Ids. Strings and Ints. That is not the problem

Comment: I would compare the versions of Android on the various phones you are testing and make sure you are testing all the possible versions.  I've noticed thing I had working perfectly for 2.2, don't work with 2.3 because of a subtle change to the system.  Look at the stats in your Developer Console to determine which versions are running your app and it may clue you in on a version you need to test.

Also, I've noticed something that works on my Motorola phone doesn't work the same on my wife's Samsung phone and tablet.

Comment: Yeah, thats a good idea. Do you know how this could be achieved? Just se Platform: OTHERS in Dev. Console

Comment: I would start with the major API releases (7, 8, 9...) and make sure you've tested on them.